# Reading a .txt file into a parallel array

Tags: java, arrays

I need some assistance with my program. Using an example program that was similar I was able to get the basic layout of everything I needed to do. Right now my main questions is if my code is correct for the first part. I want it to read the data from my data file into a parallel array. I included my entire program for reference of the layout, but for now I'm just trying to read the data file into an array. Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed or if my formatting is wrong.

Data File (patient.txt):

11111,Smith,Norris,Thyroid,1000.00
11112,Obama,Norris,Lasek,500.00
11113,Hoover,Norris,Dental,100.00
11114,Cena,Norris,Lasek,500.00
11115,Leto,Norris,Thyroid,1000.00
22221,Clark,Bond,Thyroid,1000.00
22222,Chang,Bond,Lasek,500.00
22223,Dent,Bond,Dental,100.00
22224,Nixon,Bond,Lasek,500.00
22225,Washington,Bond,Dental,100.00
33331,Jones,Lee,Dental,100.00
33332,Ross,Lee,Lasek,500.00
33333,Gates,Lee,Thyroid,1000.00
33334,Johnson,Lee,Thyroid,1000.00
33335,Carter,Lee,Dental,100.00
Program (class is Patient_Reports)
`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Patient_Reports {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int selection;
            String pnumber;
            Patient_Reports patient = new Patient_Reports();
            patient.start_system();
            pnumber = patient.menu();
            selection = Integer.parseInt(pnumber);
            while(selection !=3)
            {
                if(selection==1)
                    patient.All_Information_Report();
                else
                if(selection==2)
                    patient.Surgeries_Doctor_Report();
                else
                if(selection==3)
                    patient.Surgeries_Type_Report();
                else
                if(selection==4)
                    patient.Doctor_Fees_Report();
                else
                if(selection==5)
                    patient.Average_Fees_Report();
                pnumber = patient.menu();
                selection = Integer.parseInt(pnumber);
            }//while loop
            patient.Exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }//main method
    //Read Data File
    int count=-1,i;
    int    [] id = new int [10];
    String [] patient = new String [10];
    String [] doctor = new String [10];
    String [] surgery = new String [10];
    double [] cost = new double [10];

void start_system()
{
    String newLine;
    try
    {
        //define a file valiable for Buffered read
        BufferedReader Patient_Reports = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patient.txt"));
        //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
        while ((newLine = Patient_Reports.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //there is a "," between each data item in each line
            StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,",");
            count=count+1;
            id[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
            patient[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
            doctor[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
            surgery[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
            cost[count] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
        }//while loop
        Patient_Reports.close();
    }//end try
    catch (IOException error)
    {
        //there was an error on the file writing
        System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
    }//error on read
}//end start_system
//Method for Menu of Reports
String menu()
{
    String pnum;
    String Output =  "Reports" + "\n" +"1. All_Information_Report" + "\n" +
            "2. Surgeries_Doctor_Report" + "\n" +
            "3. Surgeries_Type_Report" + "\n" +
            "4. Doctor_Fees_Report" + "\n" +
            "5. Average_Fees_Report" + "\n" +
            "6. Exit" + "\n" +
            " " + "\n" +
            "Select a Report >";
    pnum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            Output, "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    return pnum;
}//end menu
```

/*   Placeholder for the Reports

```
//All_Information_Report Report containing all of the information

void All_Information_Report()
{
    System.out.println("All_Information_Report");
    for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(id[i] + " " + patient[i] + " " + doctor[i] + " " + surgery[i] + " " + cost[i] + " ");
    }//for loop
}//end report

//Surgeries_Doctor_Report Report on all surgeries of a specific doctor (prompt for the doctor)

void Surgeries_Doctor_Report()
{
    System.out.println("Surgeries_Doctor_Report");
    for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(id[i] + " " + patient[i] + " " + doctor[i] + " " + surgery[i] + " " + cost[i] + " ");
    }//for loop
}//end report

//Surgeries_Type_Report Report on all surgeries of a specific type(Prompt for the surgery type)

void Surgeries_Type_Report()
{
    System.out.println("Surgeries_Type_Report");
    for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(id[i] + " " + patient[i] + " " + doctor[i] + " " + surgery[i] + " " + cost[i] + " ");
    }//for loop
}//end report

//Doctor_Fees_Report Report on the total amount of fees paid to each doctor

void Doctor_Fees_Report()
{
    System.out.println("Doctor_Fees_Report");
    for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(id[i] + " " + patient[i] + " " + doctor[i] + " " + surgery[i] + " " + cost[i] + " ");
    }//for loop
}//end report

//Average_Fees_Report Report on the Average Fee

void Average_Fees_Report()
{
    System.out.println("Average_Fees_Report");
    for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(id[i] + " " + patient[i] + " " + doctor[i] + " " + surgery[i] + " " + cost[i] + " ");
    }//for loop
}//end report
```

*/
    //Store Data File in Array

```
void Exit()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedWriter Patient_Reports = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("patient.txt"));
        for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
        {
            //put "," between each data item in the file
            Patient_Reports.write(id[i] + "," + patient[i] + "," + doctor[i]+ "," + surgery[i] + ","+ cost[i]+ ",");
            //write a new line in the file
            Patient_Reports.newLine();
        }//for loop
        Patient_Reports.close();
    }//end try
    catch (IOException error)
    {
        //there was an error on the write to file
        System.out.println("Error on file write " + error);
    }//end error
}//end class
```

}//end exit_system`

Comment: Are you getting the expected output? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Expected output would be a menu with 5 reports on it, but I think the code is wrong for reading the array in my program. Is there a way to isolate the reading of the array without coding the entire program? Right now when it compiles it gives me warnings that methods are missing because I haven't finished them yet. 

Basically what I want to know is if there is some way I can isolate reading the array from the rest of the program to test it, or if there are any glaring mistakes in it so I can fix it and move on with the rest of the program.

Comment: Do you mean isolate the reading of the text file into an array? Are you getting runtime errors or compile time errors?

Comment: Patient_Reports.write  
Patient_Reports.newLine();  
Patient_Reports.close();  

When I run the program I get compile errors from write, newline, and close in my void Exit area.

I don't think my program will compile correctly until it's finished being coded, should I finish writing the code for the reports and try again?

Comment: Test each method in isolation of the others -- divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, your code is **VERY** confusing and violates several OOP programming conventions.

The first (and most egregious) problem is that your static class Patient_Reports contains the main method but does not utilize this **static** entry point to declare an object or advance. So, it would behoove you to reformat your code like this:

```
public class Patient_Reports {
    Patient_Reports fields...

    public Patient_Report() {
         //start work here in Constructor

    }

    Patient_Reports methods...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Patient_Reports();
    }        

}
```

To address your main question, you would want to have some sort of generalized method you could call within your class like this:

```
 public static void writePatientReports(int[] id, String[] patient, 
      String[] doctor, String[] surgery, double[] cost) {

     BufferedWriter Student_file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("patient.txt"));
     for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
    {
        //put "," between each data item in the file
        Student_file.write(id[i] + "," + patient[i] + "," + doctor[i]+ "," + surgery[i] + ","+ cost[i]+ ",");
        //write a new line in the file
        Student_file.write("\n");
    }//for loop
    Student_file.close();
  }
```

The reason you were getting errors is because you had no methods attached to Patient_Reports like `write()` or `newLine()`.  And even if you had, you would have needlessly declared `Student_file` as a BufferedWriter object.

Further, you would do greatly in furthering your knowledge of Java and general OOP by reading [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. I'm a beginner and am trying to get back into it by taking an advanced course.  I will definitely read through that JCC link you provided and apply it to my code.

Comment: @BrandonZink you got it. If this answered your question please mark as resolved for other devs on the forum

Comment: I just noticed in looking at your response that I had a field improperly named. Buffered_Writer Student_File should have Patient_Reports instead of student file. Woops. Working on fixing the code and applying the concepts you gave me now.